# How to get the client IP from within a web service running within a docker container?

Tags: docker

I have an application that extracts the client IP making the request. When I run the application directly on a server, it works and I could get the IP.

But when I run it within a docker containing by executing this command:

```
docker run --rm -d -p 4300:4300 image
```

All of a sudden the client IP being reported is now `172.17.0.1`.

Googling around I see suggestion to pass in `--net=host` but doing this:

```
 docker run --rm --net=host -p 4300:4300 image
```

now leads to the application not being reachable. For some strange reason it looks like the application is no longer available at the specified port.

This also does not work even when I drop the -p 4300:4300 as I got a message in the console that it is not needed when --net=host is used. That is:

```
 docker run --rm --net=host -p image
```

Any suggestions on how to get this done? That is how to get the client IP from within a web service running within a docker container? I am running docker on a mac. Don't know if this has anything to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `net=host` configuration, you don't need the `-p <host>:<container>` setting, since this is only used to port forward when you use the bridge network configuration.
Just drop this flag and browse to whatever port your application listens on. It should work.

Comment: unfortunately I tried that but that does not work also. I updated the question to include this.